# Count NaN Single Column with Multiple Conditions in Other Columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, multiple-columns, nan

i cannot seem to figure this out trying many different things and there apparently is no answer across the web that i have found. I have data that has values in a single column "data" and i need to sum or count occurrences of NaN in this column based on a groupby of conditions in two other columns such as this which resembles my data below:

```
    site     data      day     month   year
0   Red      NaN        20     1       2020
1   Red      5.6        31     1       2020
2   Red      NaN         6     1       2020
3   Red      NaN         9     2       2020
3   Blue     4.5        14     1       2020
4   Blue     6.2        19     2       2020
5   Blue     NaN        11     2       2020
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
   site    month    count    sumNaN  
0  Red     1        3        2
1  Red     2        1        1
2  Blue    1        1        0
3  Blue    2        2        1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(df.assign(data=df['data'].isna())
   .groupby(['site','month'])
   ['data'].agg(['count','sum'])
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   site  month  count  sum
0  Blue      1      1    0
1  Blue      2      2    1
2   Red      1      3    2
3   Red      2      1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used named aggregation within the `agg`:

```
(df.groupby(['site', 'month'], as_index = False)
   .agg(count=('data', 'size'), 
        sumNaN=('data', lambda df: df.isna().sum())
        )
 )

   site  month  count  sumNaN
0  Blue      1      1     0.0
1  Blue      2      2     1.0
2   Red      1      3     2.0
3   Red      2      1     1.0
```